# variable value from variable name in VBA

Tags: vba

I have code that works that is

```
With ClientForm
    If retainerFee <> .RetainerFeeTB.Value Then
        LabelLB.AddItem (.RetainerFeeLabel.Caption)
        BeforeLB.AddItem (retainerFee) 'variable Value
        AfterLB.AddItem (.RetainerFeeTB) 'Textbox.value
    End If
    If less250 <> .Less250TB.Value Then
        LabelLB.AddItem (.less250label.caption)
        BeforeLB.AddItem (less250) 'variable Value
        AfterLB.AddItem (.Less250TB) 'Textbox.value
   End If
end with
```

but I'd like to make it so I don't need to writer the code for every variable that needs to be called
and this is what I have so far for that

```
With ClientForm
    For Each ctrl In .ClientMP.Pages(page).Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then
            variableName = Left(ctrl.Name, Len(ctrl.Name) - 2)
            variableValue = ??variableName??
            tBValue = ctrl.Value
            If tBValue <> variableValue Then
                labelName = variableName & "Label"
                labelCaption = .Controls(labelName).Caption
                LabelLB.AddItem (labelCaption)
                BeforeLB.AddItem (variableValue)
                AfterLB.AddItem (tBValue)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End with
```

I just don't know how to get the Variable Value

Comment: Take a look at [CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function).

Comment: Please follow these guidelines to improve your chance of getting a good answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Use a scripting Dictionary to key the values to the "name"